# Entity framework Beta 3 database, does not give DeleteOnSubmit

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I do not get context DeleteOnSubmit!!  All other functions like Add, Count, etc… work fine! Due to this, I cannot delete the record.

```
Error   1   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<mvc2db.Company_Dext>' does not contain a
definition for 'DeleteOnSubmit' and no extension method 'DeleteOnSubmit' accepting 
a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<mvc2db.Company_Dext>' could be 
found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Premium edition

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Entity Framework 5, there is no DeleteOnsubmit instead there is .Remove(record entity).